# How do I get two X displays across two monitors, working independently

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, dualhead

I'm running an nvidia card on a machine running a fresh install of 12.04.
I'm using the drivers available from the main repos. I have the program 'nvidia-settings' available.

I have an x display on each monitor. However, when I switch desktops on one monitor, the desktop on the second monitor also changes.

This is a departure from the behaviour that I had on 10.10, where I could control each monitors desktop display independently.

Is there any way to get this behaviour back on 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of settings that you can configure using the nvidia-settings. for an explanation of twinview and separate X screens [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaMultiMonitors#Differences). It sounds to me as if you might have chosen twinview when configuring the nvidia-settings. You would need to go back in to the nividia-settings manager:

[image]

It will require that you log out, then log back in order for the configuration change to take place.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi. I made sure not to choose twinview, because I knew it definitely wasn't what I wanted. My current settings show that twinview is not selected. I have it set to 'seperate X screen'.

Comment: Tomorrow at work I will check out my configuration at work and see if I can try and help further. If no one provides better info by then.